# Shutdown asp.net core application

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I started to learn ASP.NET Core and cannot find a way to shutdown asp.net core application if it was started from Visual Studio by "Run without debugging"

If I start it from console by `dotnet run` it can be shut down by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

How I can find my running app and stop it when it was started from VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your taskbar at the right, there'll be in a icon for IIS Express. Right-click that and you can choose to stop individual sites or IIS Express entirely. You may need to expand the system tray area to see the IIS Express icon.